# Parametrized return type-hint with pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-typing

I have a function that can return different types, *e.g.* either a `dict` or a `pd.DataFrame`. To provide appropriate type-hints, I naively thought I could just do sth like this to achieve this:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def get_obj(key: str, typ: T = Any) -> T:
    # load obj using key
    return obj
```

But now when I do this

```py
df = get_obj(key="asd", typ=pd.DataFrame)
```

my linters think `df` is the class `pd.DataFrame`, not an instance of `pd.DataFrame`. *E.g.* it says `(variable) df Type[DataFrame]` (and not `(variable) df DataFrame`), offers me different instantiation methods, and is displeased when I do sth like `df.loc`.

I know I could do sth like this:

```py
@overload
def get_obj(key: str, is_df: Literal[False]) -> Any:
    ...

@overload
def get_obj(key: str, is_df: Literal[True]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    ...

def get_obj(key: str, is_df: bool = False):
    # load obj using key
    return obj
```

but then I have to hard-code all possible types.

Comment: `typ: T = Any` doesn't make any sense. "my linters think df is the class pd.DataFrame, not an instance of pd.DataFrame. " **because that is what is going on**. You provided *the class, `pd.DataFrame` as a default argument to the `typ` parameter* You seem to be confusing type annotations with default values

Comment: Fundamentally, `typ` and `is_df` seem to be relying on *your knowledge* of what the return type will be. But it *doesn't actually matter what you pass to those paramters*, so it's not really correctly type annotated. At this point, you might as well just use a `cast`

Comment: So, instead of `df : pd.DataFrame = get_obj(x, pd.Dataframe)` at the call site, since that second argument *doesn't* actually do anything and *in no way guarantees that `get_obj` returns a `pd.DataFrame`*, the standard way would be `df : pd.DataFrame = cast(pd.DataFrame, get_obj(x))` at the call site.

Comment: This is actually also a good answer. But nevertheless the real answer below is good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very cool question! I have working code (which produces correct intellisense based on the given `typ` in your function) on the below.

The reason the linter doesn't get it, is because you are giving it a generic type, rather than the `Type` type. The content of the `typ` parameter is after all a reference to a `Type`, not an instance or a string.

Luckily, the `typing` library has the `Type` type, which facilitates just this use case.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type
import pandas as pd


item1: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
item2: int = 2
item3: str = "HelloWorld!"

x = {
    "one": item1,
    "two": item2,
    "three": item3
}

T = TypeVar("T")

def get_obj(key: str, typ: Type[T]) -> T:
    # load obj using key
    obj: T = x[key]
    print(type(obj))
    return obj


y = get_obj(key="one", typ=pd.DataFrame)
```

Note that, because the contents of the `typ` parameter is variable, we still need to use TypeVar.

The above code will make the IDE see variable `y` as a pd.dataframe. If you would assign it with `y = get_obj(key="one", typ=int)` your IDE will think that the object is of type `int`, while it actually is a `pd.dataframe`.

Comment: Unless I'm. missing something, this doesn't make sense and wouldn't pass static type checkers. the `typ` you pass *has no effect* on the return value, this seems to rely on understanding which string you pass to `key` entirely, in which case, `Literal` overloads would make more sense.

Comment: Correct, but the question was about type-hinting (e.g. autocomplete). This works for that. I used a fixed dictionary, so static type checkers would use that. But in dynamic dictionaries in which the type of the items are unknown, you might want to use this.

Comment: Right, but **this is an incorrect type hint**. That is my entire point. It really would be better to just use a `cast` here instead of an incorrect type hint. In the case of dynamic dictionaries, this makes even less sense, because then *how would you know what to pass to it?*

Comment: Why is it an incorrect typehint? This is what OP was asking, and provides the correct outcome that he/she sought. I don't see why it is incorrect?

Comment: As in it doesn't correctly describe the behavior of the function. As in `def foo() -> int: return "foo"`. Again, the behavior the OP seems to desire would be accomplished with a `cast` generally speaking.

Comment: So, instead of `df : pd.DataFrame = get_obj(x, pd.Dataframe)` at the call site, since that second argument *doesn't* actually do anything and *in no way guarantees that `get_obj` returns a `pd.DataFrame`*, the standard way would be `df : pd.DataFrame = cast(pd.DataFrame, get_obj(x))` at the call site

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks! My `get_obj` unpickles an object which can be `pd.DataFrame`, `List[str]`, `Dict[str, Any]`... and while I pass the key, I know what type of object it is that will be returned. I just want to make intellisense aware of it